# how to know if a process which run in the background finished or not

Tags: c, process, operating-system, execv

I coded a basic shell in C for executing basic commands like ls , pwd , ... 
 
I have a feature that can make a process run in the background instead of waiting until its done for example : ls & instead of ls (I have a list that contains the processes that run in the background now)
The whole thing is that I want to know when a process is done or not , so I can remove it from the list .
thanks

Comment: There must be dozens, if not more freely available examples of shells that do this… perhaps you should search for just one of them and read its source?

Comment: do you have a specific one ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642775/where-to-find-example-source-code-for-a-very-simple-linux-shell seems to have promise. Edit: They might actually be too simple for what you need, but finding any simple shell that supports background tasks is likely to have what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a child process terminates, `SIGCHLD` signal is sent to parent. `waitpid` function with `WNOHANG` flag can be used to check if a child process has terminated or is still running. Probably, you'll want to combine those both methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now I created a function called signalHandler to handle the SIGCHLD signal , that when it comes, the parent process waits for the child using : pid = waitpid(-1, &cstatus, WNOHANG);

Comment: What I didn't understand is that how we can wait for a process that just sent a signal which indicates the it has already finished !

Comment: It's not the process that sends signal, it's kernel that sends it on behalf of terminated process.